# Using BitmapFactory.Options causes changes in BitmapFactory

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

What I wanted to achieve is being able to calculate the height and width of a Bitmap from an inputstream without actually changing BitmapFactory.Options

This is what I did:

```
private Boolean testSize(InputStream inputStream){
    BitmapFactory.Options Bitmp_Options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmp_Options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(getResources(), new TypedValue(), inputStream, new Rect(), Bitmp_Options);
    int currentImageHeight = Bitmp_Options.outHeight;
    int currentImageWidth = Bitmp_Options.outWidth;
    if(currentImageHeight > 200 || currentImageWidth > 200){
        Object obj = map.remove(pageCounter);
        Log.i("Page recycled", obj.toString());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now the main problem here is that it changes the BitmapFactory.Options to a state that can't decodeStream properly.

My question is there another way of resetting BitmapFactory.Options? or another possible solution?

Another method: (Note* that originalBitmap is null when the top method is applied)

This is was my original code:

```
Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InpStream);
```

Applying Deev's and Nobu Game's suggestion: (no change)

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InpStream,null,options);
```

Comment: Why not create another BitmapFactory.Options object?

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I am still having this issue no image is displayed on another method I have what is updated above.

Comment: I am starting to think that this is a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to read from the same stream twice. A stream doesn't work as a byte array. Once you've read data from it, you cannot read it again unless you reset the stream position. You can try to call InputStream.reset() after your first call to decodeStream() but not all InputStreams support this method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to reuse your Options object (which is not the case in your code sample by the way), then how are you trying to reuse it? What is the error message, what goes wrong?
Are you trying to reuse the Options object for actually decoding the Bitmap? Then just set inJustDecodeBounds to false.

Comment: I am not trying to reuse it. No error message. I am not reusing the option object. For the last one I created BitmapFactory.Options object and still no good. No image gets displayed when I try to do   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
  Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InpStream,null,options);

Answer (score 0):

A simple class to copy InputStream when inputStream.Mark and inputStream.Reset doesn't work.

To call:

```
CopyInputStream copyStream = new CopyInputStream(zip);
InputStream inputStream = copyStream.getIS();
```

I hope this helps someone. Here is the code.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class CopyInputStream {

private InputStream inputStream;
private ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutPutStream;

/*
 * Copies the InputStream to be reused
 */
public CopyInputStream(InputStream is){
    this.inputStream = is;
    try{
        int chunk = 0;
        byte[] data = new byte[256];

        while(-1 != (chunk = inputStream.read(data)))
        {
            byteOutPutStream.write(data, 0, chunk);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
/*
 * Calls the finished inputStream
 */
public InputStream getIS(){
    return (InputStream)new ByteArrayInputStream(byteOutPutStream.toByteArray());
}
```

}